# Allure plugin for VSTS returns error: Unknown Test Runner

Tags: nunit, azure-devops, allure, nunit-console

The VSTS task: Generate Allure Report is failed.

**The error is :**
Unable to process command '##vso[results.publish type=Allure;mergeResults=true;publishRunAttachments=true;resultFiles=D:\a\1\s\allure-report\34;]' successfully. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
Unknown Test Runner.

**Question:** can it be a bug or problem connected to configs?

**Configurations:**
.Net version: 4.6.1, Nunit3, Nunit3 allure adapter

Task to run tests is a Command Line task where I used nunit3-console.exe to run test.

**Configurations for Allure plugin:**

Results directory : allure-results
Target directory : allure-report/$(Build.BuildNumber)

The output logs:

> ****************************************************************************** Starting: Generate Allure Report
>
> ---
>
> ============================================================================== Task         : Generate Allure Report Description  : Generates Allure
>   report based on the test results Version      : 1.0.0 Author       :
>   Molecula Help         : [More
>   Information](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki)
>   ============================================================================== C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
>   D:\a_tasks\AllureGenerate_5c975f9d-1c3a-469f-b7c2-8907bf3eacfb\1.0.0\node_modules\allure-commandline\bin\allure
>   generate --output D:\a\1\s\allure-report\34 D:\a\1\s\allure-results
>   Command aborted due to exception {}.
>   org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an
>   error: 1 (Exit value: 1)  at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   ru.yandex.qatools.allure.command.ReportGenerate.runUnsafe(ReportGenerate.java:48)
>     at
>   ru.yandex.qatools.allure.command.AbstractCommand.run(AbstractCommand.java:52)
>     at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.CommandLine.main(CommandLine.java:46)
>   org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an
>   error: 1 (Exit value: 1)  at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   ru.yandex.qatools.allure.command.ReportGenerate.runUnsafe(ReportGenerate.java:48)
>     at
>   ru.yandex.qatools.allure.command.AbstractCommand.run(AbstractCommand.java:52)
>     at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.CommandLine.main(CommandLine.java:46)   at
>   ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.AllureReportGenerator.generate(AllureReportGenerator.java:58)
>     at
>   ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.AllureReportGenerator.generate(AllureReportGenerator.java:53)
>     at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.AllureMain.main(AllureMain.java:48)
>   Exception in thread "main"
>   ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.ReportGenerationException: Could not
>   find any allure results   at
>   ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.AllureReportGenerator.generate(AllureReportGenerator.java:58)
>     at
>   ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.AllureReportGenerator.generate(AllureReportGenerator.java:53)
>     at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.AllureMain.main(AllureMain.java:48)
>   Unable to process command '##vso[results.publish
>   type=Allure;mergeResults=true;publishRunAttachments=true;resultFiles=D:\a\1\s\allure-report\34;]'
>   successfully. Please reference documentation
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296) Unknown Test Runner.

Comment: Can you show the whole build log by setting the variable `system.debug` as `true`?

Comment: What is your Results directory?

Comment: Hi Eddie, I am using the default allure-results directory

Comment: @Marina, Currently I have no chance to run the build with debug logs, but I will try to keep you updated as soon as I do it.

Comment: @RuslanKryvosheiev - Did you find solution for this? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The default setting directory "allure-results"  in the Allure task usually does not point to the actual path to result directory correctly since the path is different in different projects and environment. You need to update the setting to configure it to the actual path to the result directory manually.

According to the information you provided, the path to the result could be like this:

```
$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\SolutionFolder\ProjectFolder\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\allure-results
```

Comment: Thank you Eddie, I think I did the same what you provided in your answer, e.g.: my Results directory path is : NUnit.Tests1/NUnit.Test1/allure-results/
I am able to generate the allure-results with Allure Command Line via VSTF, but in case of this plugin I am getting an error.

Comment: @RuslanKryvosheiev But the logs and your screenshot indicated that the directory you configured in the Allure task was just "allure-results" rather than "NUnit.Tests1/NUnit.Test1/allure-results".